# Achieve 921 and 999 by 39 loops as whole numbers

Tags: php, math, logic

I am in a situation where I need to achieve divide 921/39 and by giving whole numbers (39 times for loop), achieve 921 again.

```
$packagesCount = count($packages);      // = 39
$averageWeight = 921/$packagesCount;    // = 23.6153846154

foreach ($packages as $package) {
    $package['Weight'] = "<whole number>";
}
```

The reason is, I need to give the api whole numbers but the total should be 921. Thus, I can't give round numbers.

---

One way I thought of is:

```
$packagesCount = count($packages);      // = 39
$averageWeight = 921/$packagesCount;    // = 23.6153846154
$remainder = ceil($averageWeight);      // = 24 

foreach ($packages as $package) {
    $package['Weight'] = floor($averageWeight);

    if ($remainder > 0) {
        $package['Weight'] += 1;            
        $remainder -= 1;
    }
}
```

But trying it with `999` total weight doesn't work with this approach; instead of 999 in the end, it gives `39 * 25 + 26 = 1001`.

For 999, I should use `39 * 25 + 24 = 999` but how?

Comment: See: modulo operator. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`intdiv`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) and modulo [`%`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
$packagesCount = count($packages);     
$averageWeight = $totalWeight/$packagesCount;
$wholeWeight = intdiv($totalWeight,$packagesCount);
$weightRest = $totalWeight % $packagesCount;
// totalWeight = wholeWeight * packagesCount + weightRest 

$i = 0;
foreach ($packages as $key => $package) {
    $w = $wholeWeight;
    if ($i < $weightRest) {
     $w += 1;
    }
    $i+= 1;
    $packages[$key]['Weight'] = $w;
}
```

The idea is that each package while have at least `intdiv` weight and first `weightRest` packages will have +1 to their weight. In such a way you will exactly match your `totalWeight`.

See also an [online demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6a84e77e30bbbee6b657cdb4d44886556bfba37)

P.S. PHP is not my language so the code might be very non-idiomatic. Still I hope it conveys the idea.

Comment: Thanks, your approach is also interesting. I also solved it with `floor()` & modulo `%`

Comment: @senty, `floor(a/b)` is the same as `intdiv(a,b)` at least for positive `a` and `b`  but I believe `intdiv` better conveys the logic.